# postgres sql statement with subquery

Tags: sql, postgresql

Below is some pseudocode that I need to retrieve data from a postgresql database.  The subquery is where I am having trouble figuring out how to do correctly.

I need to include any record that has that has an output_type='TEXT' and if the output_type does not have 'TEXT' use a different criteria to ensure it is included.

```
Select * from tablename
left join table2 on table2.fk_id = tablename.pkid
where table2.letterid = 5 
and table2.pkid not exist( select * from table3 where
if the table3.output = 'text'
include the record 
else not table3.output = 'text'
if table3.sentdate is null
 the record)
```

Comment: `not exists` subquery is not correlated with outer query. Did you mean `not in`?

Comment: Please demonstrate what you need by example; include demonstration data for all three tables, and then the results you require for that demonstration data. For more information please read; [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS (` is how I do this generally. You can join with the other statement's tables in there, as I'm doing in this example with `table2.pkid`.

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (
  table2.fk_id = tablename.pkid
  AND table2.letterid = 5
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM table3
    WHERE table3.pkid = table2.pkid
    AND ...  -- I don't quite follow what you're trying to do with the if/else, but it'd go here
  )
);
```

`table2.pkid NOT IN (SELECT table3.pkid ...` also works for this. Not sure if it'll have the same performance or not, but personally I prefer the flexibility of `NOT EXISTS` anyway.

Comment: Left join and where clause interact in such a way as to revert to inner join. Where clause needs to be moved to join predicate (both the assertion on letter id, and the correlated sub-query)

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for the catch, always forget that.